# Renaming columns of many dfs with the elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have 5 dataframes called control1,control2,control3,control4,control5. I'm renaming their columns. But i want to rename the column named 10 (integer name) with the elements in files for each one.
Something like this:

```
    control1.rename(columns={10:'02042020.txt'}, inplace=True)
    control2.rename(columns={10:'05032020.txt'}, inplace=True)
    #...... etc etc
```

This is my code:

```
        lista_controles=[control1,control2,control3,control4,control5]
        files=['02042020.txt','05032020.txt','12032020.txt','19032020.txt','26032020.txt']
        for df in lista_controles:
            df.rename(columns={2:'NOMBRE_ESTACION'}, inplace=True)
            for i in files 
               df.rename(columns={10:f'{i}'}, inplace=True)
```

But is only renaming with the first element of the list (02042020.txt). How can i solve this? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when `df.rename(columns={10:f'{i}'}, inplace=True)` first runs, it changes the name "10" to "02042020.txt". At the second iteration, there is no any column named "10" anymore, so it does nothing, because it just has been changed to "02042020.txt".

You could try:

```py
for i, df in enumerate(lista_controles):
    df.rename(columns={2:'NOMBRE_ESTACION'}, inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns={10:files[i]}, inplace=True)
```

To make this work, make sure you have equal number of elements in `lista_controles` and `files` though. If there are not, there are other ways to do it.

Comment: You're welcome. Here actually the only thing that makes difference is `enumerate`. You can just Google it and learn what it is. The rest of it is just logic, and it improves by practicing. *https://www.hackerrank.com/* is a really good place for practicing for python.